# Open application window on left moust click Ubuntu 18 / Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, menu, tray

Installed fresh Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome, then installed Skype and Slack. And now in my system tray (notifications area, applications list, ...) I have icons of this running applications. When I click on the app icon I see context menu instead of application window. How can I return old behavior (open app instead of context menu) without changing Gnome to metacity / classic and so on? Is it possible with gnome tweak tools ?